# Opening a txt.file in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to open a simple txt.file in c++ (visual studio), but are only triggering "else".
codes.txt is together with the main file in source files and are included. This is more or less how it looks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("codes.txt");
  if (file.is_open())
  { 
    std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
  }
  else 
  {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have file open in any editor, then try closing it and running the program again. The code looks correct. Also, do check if the file IS in the directory where the program is being run.

Comment: Do you have any experience wherabout I have to do more than than "add a existing object" with the txt file. Like referring to it in the program?

Answer (score 0):

The txt file did not exist in the folder of the program. Runned perfectly after it was included.